# String Formatting;-Calling values from a dictionary to select by attribute in fc

Tags: arcpy, string, format

New to python. In the code below, I create a dictionary b={} and wish to call keys to select by attribute. All goes well until I am required to format strings to come up with whereclause. I am constantly getting an error.

```
 b = {}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tc, (field)) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            if row[0] not in b: #I am using 'not in' to test value in dictionary
                b[row[0]] = [row[1],row[2]]

    PATCH_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "PATCH_lyr")
    for k, v in b.iteritems():

            print k, v

   PATCH_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "PATCH_lyr")
for k, v in b.iteritems():

        print k, v

frt = b.iteritems()
for ind in frt:
        whereClause =  "IDO = '{0}'".format(ind)
        kala = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(PATCH_lyr, 'NEW_SELECTION', whereClause
```

)

Comment: What is the full error, including line number, that you are getting when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: @Hornbydd, it is  a text field and so@ PolyGeo 's formatting worked. It didnt run through theough . It threw the error, raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that IDO is a text field, instead of:

```
whereClause =  """ "IDO" = %s """ % ind
```

I would try:

```
whereClause =  "IDO = '{0}'".format(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this coding run. It is able to select, copy features and append to different files based on count.

```
import arcpy
import csv

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

tc = "C:\Mapping\Road Reserve Patches for Validation\Working\RoadReserveValidation.gdb\GeoMasterList"
fc = r"C:\Mapping\Road Reserve Patches for Validation\Working\RoadReserveValidation.gdb\patch16112018"
dicts = r"C:\Mapping\Delete Folder\dict.csv"
target_layer = r"C:\Mapping\Road Reserve Patches for Validation\Working\SortedOutput.gdb\Relatives_Of_GeoMasterList"
target_layer1 = r"C:\Mapping\Road Reserve Patches for Validation\Working\InTheirOwnStand.gdb\OwnStand"
field = 'IDO', 'GisKey', 'PatchTenure'
fields = 'IDO'
outTable = "Output_Times"
csv_columns = ['IDO', 'GisKey', 'PatchTenure']




f_list =[]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tc, (fields)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        f_list.append(row[0])

    print list (enumerate(f_list))

for i in range(len(f_list)):
        whereClause = "IDO = '{}'".format(f_list[i])


       #Select and count

        PATCH_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "PATCH_lyr")

        sh = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(PATCH_lyr, 'NEW_SELECTION', whereClause)#Carry out the
        cnt1 = arcpy.GetCount_management(sh) # Counting the selected and copied features
        count = int(cnt1.getOutput(0))

        #arcpy.env.workspace = r"W:\2018_2019\Projects\GeoMaster Validation\Road Reserve Patches for Validation\Working\Output.gdb"
        print (whereClause)
        print(count)

        if count == 1:
               # print (whereClause)
                    #shef=arcpy.CreateUniqueName('{}'.format(f_list[i]))


                #arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(PATCH_lyr, shef) # Copy features
                print("In My own Stand, leave me alone: " + str(cnt1))

                append_layer = sh
                inData = [append_layer]

                arcpy.Append_management(inData, target_layer1)#append features
        elif count > 1:
               # print (whereClause)
                    #shef=arcpy.CreateUniqueName('{}'.format(f_list[i]))


                #arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(PATCH_lyr, shef)
                print("The number of selected records is: " + str(cnt1))

                append_layer = sh
                inData = [append_layer]

                arcpy.Append_management(inData, target_layer)#append features

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(PATCH_lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION") #clear selection to allow the code to loop if f_list not completed
```